Does the Go runtime guarantee that there are at least as many OS Threads as there are Contexts (P)?
can someone confirm something for me; Does the Go runtime guarantee that there are at least as many OS Threads as there are Contexts (P)? That is, if, for example, GOMAXPROCS is equal to 5, will there be at least 5 OS Threads?

Note: "the Go runtime" isn't a thing. There are multiple Go runtimes.

What do you mean by multiple runtimes? From different versions of the language?

A short answer: In general case, it should promise, but it's not strictly guaranteed.
GOMAXPROCS won't control the number of os threads directly, it will control the number of Logical Processors (P). Each logical processor can run one Goroutine(G) at a time.
Goroutine(G): These are the lightweight user-space threads managed by the Go runtime.
Os Threads(M) are the actual operating system threads that execute Goroutines. The Go runtime can create more OS threads than the number of logical processors.
So in normal case, there is not 1to1 mapping between Goroutine and OS thread, it's determined by Go runtime with consideration about performance.
There are some scenarios that OS thread less than GOMAXPROCS (I think it's what you want to ask, because you mention "at least"):

if your task is very lightweight, the Go runtime may optimize thread usage to reduce unnecessary system thread overhead.
in the initial phase, the Go runtime haven't created enough enough system threads to match the GOMAXPROCS setting.


runtime.NumCPU returns the number of usable logical CPUs, not GOMAXPROCS. The latter sets a limit of what will be used.

“At least n OS threads” is not a useful characteristic.
GOMAXPROCS is not in the Go language specification, but in runtime:

The GOMAXPROCS variable limits the number of operating system threads that can execute user-level Go code simultaneously. There is no limit to the number of threads that can be blocked in system calls on behalf of Go code; those do not count against the GOMAXPROCS limit.

It also says “This call will go away when the scheduler improves.”
Why is that? As mentioned, you can have some OS threads blocked in system calls. To use your CPU to full capacity, you need at least as many unblocked (executing) OS threads as there are available CPU cores. Having more is slightly wasteful, since you can't execute more code in parallel and will resort to os thread switch, which is more expensive that goroutine scheduling.
So this number is a hint to the scheduler. The real number of unblocked threads will obviously deviate from this number, since the scheduler needs time to adapt to changing circumstances, like threads getting blocked or freed - or it might make total different decisions, depending on the implementation.
You mostly use this call to limit the number of used os threads, for example in a cloud environment to make resources available to other processes.
There is an excellent profiler that helps you observe your process and understand how it performs in a certain environment. Just keep in mind that Go is improving and things will change (for the better).
